# The OK button on my form doesn't show up when first launched, it does show up if I relaunch

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a form and should have the OK button Grayed out every time the script is run however, I have to run the Script twice for the OK to appear. Not sure what's is going on.
[Missing OK Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3tz.png)

Variable Area

```
Import-Module (Join-Path $(Split-Path $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH) ConfigurationManager.psd1)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

File Name Set-OSDComputerNamePrompt-TST.ps1

```
# Below is one of the Array's I'm adding    
$ADSites=@("S01","S02","S03")
# Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# $ADSites = (Get-ADReplicationSite -filter *).Name
```

I can't get the Get-ADReplicationSite to work in WinPE

```
$ADSiteS01=@("AAA","BBB","CCC")
$ADSiteS02=@("DDD","EEE","FFF")
$ADSiteS03=@("GGG","HHH","JJJ")
```

Create Form

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,250)
$Form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,250)
$Form.MaximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(425,250)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"
$Form.Text = "Just a Form"
$Form.TopMost = $true
```

Create Combo Boxes

```
$Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$Combobox1.Location = '26,25'
$Combobox1.Size = '105,20'
$Combobox1.items.AddRange($ADSites)
$combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$combobox2.Location = '143,25'
$combobox2.Size = '105,20'
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$Form.Controls.Add($combobox2)
```

Create Text Box

```
$textBoxFPS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBoxFPS.Location = '26,75'
$textBoxFPS.Size = '55,20'
$textBoxFPS.Text = 'Test'
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFPS)
```

Control what can be entered in the Text Box

```
$textBoxFPS.MaxLength = 6
$textBoxFPS.Add_TextChanged({
$this.text = $this.Text -replace '\D'})
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxFPS)
```

Add Labels for the Combo Boxes

```
$lbADSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbADSub.Text = "Select AD Site"
$lbADSub.Top = 5
$lbADSub.Left = 26
$lbADSub.Autosize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($lbADSub)
$lbDeptSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lbDeptSub.Text = "Select Department"
$lbDeptSub.Top = 5
$lbDeptSub.Left = 143
$lbDeptSub.Autosize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($lbDeptSub)
$lbFPSSub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
$lbFPSSub.Text = "Asset Tag (Only Numbers Allowed)"
$lbFPSSub.Top = 55
$lbFPSSub.Left = 26
$lbFPSSub.Autosize = $true
$form.Controls.Add($lbFPSSub)
```

CheckBox

```
$chkThis = New-Object Windows.Forms.checkbox
$chkThis.Text = "Verify New Computer Name"
$chkThis.Left = 26
$chkThis.Top = 105
$chkThis.AutoSize = $true
$chkThis.Checked = $false
$form.Controls.Add($chkThis)
```

Label for choice selection

```
$labelClub = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelClub.Location = '20,130'
$labelClub.Size = '280,20'
$labelClub.Text = "-"
$form.Controls.Add($labelClub)
```

Create Ok and Cancel Buttons

```
$buttonPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
$buttonPanel.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,40)
$buttonPanel.Dock = "Bottom"
```

Creating the Ok Button

```
$okButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Top = $cancelButton.Top
$okButton.Left = $cancelButton.Left - $okButton.Width - 5
$okButton.Text = "Ok" 
$okButton.DialogResult = "Ok" 
$okButton.Anchor = "Left" 
$okButton.Enabled = $false
```

Creating the Cancel Button

```
$cancelButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Height - $cancelButton.Height - 10
$cancelButton.Left = $buttonPanel.Width - $cancelButton.Width - 10
$cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$cancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
$cancelButton.Anchor = "Right"
```

Add the buttons to the button panel

```
$buttonPanel.Controls.Add($okButton)
$buttonPanel.Controls.Add($cancelButton)
```

Add the button panel to the form

```
$form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel)
```

Set Default actions for the buttons

```
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
```

Now we do stuff Populate Combobox 2 When Combobox 1 changes

```
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$ComboBox2.Items.Clear() 
$combobox2.Text = $null  
Switch ($ComboBox1.Text) {
"S01"{
$ADSiteS01 | ForEach { 
$combobox2.Items.Add($_)
}}
"S02"{
$ADSiteS02 | ForEach {
$combobox2.Items.Add($_)
}}
"S03"{
$ADSiteS03 | ForEach {
$combobox2.Items.Add($_)
}}}
$labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})

$ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})

$textBoxFPS.add_TextChanged({
$labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
})
```

Do something when the state of the checkbox changes

```
$chkThis.Add_CheckStateChanged({
If ($chkThis.Checked) {
$okButton.enabled = $true
}
Else {
$okButton.enabled = $true
}})

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: It's just a guess, that it could be an additional problem (so not definitely solving the issue) that the `$okButton` has dependency on `$cancelButton`, so don't you want to change the order of `$buttonPanel.Controls.Add`'s ?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. You create the OK button first, but its position is dependant on the Cancelbutton you have not created yet. On the second run, the Cancelbutton **IS** known, so the OK button can get its position. Change the creation order of the OK and Cancel buttons. A tip: append one final line `$Form.Dispose()` to the code, so the form will not linger in memory when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Theo's and my comment above, please add `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` to the top of your script.
See the reason why:

```
$v1 = 2 + $v2
$v1

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$v1 = 2 + $v2
$v1
```

This might not solve your issue completely, but gives you an error if your code is using uninitialized variables if you run pieces of code in a specific order (and helps to avoid falling into other  problems, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6).

Comment: I'm not able to vote but this answered my question. Between both the comments by David and Theo along with the Set-StrictMode solved it.
Thank you

Comment: If it solved your problem, you do not vote, you need to accept it as an answer.

Comment: If I have a follow up question, do I create a new Question or ??

Comment: Well... it depends on what do you mean by follow-up: if it is a 'How do I ...' type of question, your answer maybe only a Google search away. So search before you ask. Otherwise I would say that ask a new question, but you need to localize your problem in the code, because you should not post the entire thing over and over again - due to this you can put your question here in the comment if you are really stuck.